How to apply attributes from one instance collection to instances from another collection
I have two collections.
One that contains three Empties at the center of the Geonodes container, with varying rotation (i.e. Orbits)
One that contains three objects with varying position (i.e. Planets).
I am trying to set things up so that the Geonode setup generates three curve circles, positioned at the center of the container, each having the rotation of the Orbits and whose scale would be the distance between the Planets and the Orbits/Centerpoint of the Container.
Except… I can’t figure out how to get attributes from one collection and apply it to the other. I’ve tried using both the Orbits and the Planets as the baseline, with no dice.
From my understanding it’s something to do with how it’s either failing to load in the Instances of one collection at the same time as the other, as such not loading the corresponding attribute, OR it’s trying to apply that attribute to the wrong instance.
How do I do this properly?
My attempts that are clearly missing SOMETHING


I think the best answer to this question wouldn't address the exact issue of OP, but just how to debug an issue :D The spreadsheet and viewer are your friends, at various points you should be able to investigate if you get the data you expect or not.

The solution ended up being to, instead of using Capture Attributes to get the position of the planets, to utilize Sample Index that is fed the Index Attribute of the Orbit Instances in order to properly assign each orbit to each planet.

